# Django Python uploading a file to a specific folder

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I am working on a Django app and I want the users to be able to upload a `csv` file to a folder in the server. Appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Comment: add your settings, your views, and templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the django `FileField` and that lets you upload the file to the specified folder directly through admin panel and same can be done using the form for normal user.

```
upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/your-folder/')
```

Comment: I did that , but when i upload a file to the specific folder. I check the folder but the folder is empty. my view is  def uploadfunc(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
  form =uploadfileform(request.POST,request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   return render_to_response('upload_successful.html')
 else:
  form=uploadfileform()
 return render(request, 'upload.html',{'form':form})

Comment: add your `form.html` here.

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
  <!--  <button type="submit">Upload</button>-->
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" >
  </form>

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is in the `MEDIA_ROOT` and/or `MEDIA_URL` settings in `settings.py`, but I'm wrong quite a bit

Comment: Thanks you where right. There problem was in the MEDIA_ROOT. By the way is it possible to overwrite upload file that has the same name with the current uploaded one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my complete solution

```html
#view.py
def uploadfunc(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
  form =uploadfileform(request.POST,request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   return render_to_response('upload_successful.html')
 else:
  form=uploadfileform()
 return render(request, 'upload.html',{'form':form})


#models.py
class uploadfolder(models.Model):
    """ my application """
    File_to_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='')


#forms.py
#uploading file form
class uploadfileform(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model=uploadfolder
  fields=('File_to_upload',)


#upload.html
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'uploadfunc'%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
  <!--  <button type="submit">Upload</button>-->
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File" >
  </form>


#settings.py 

MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/vmachines/registry/files/"
MEDIA_URL = "files/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Clients can send files via multi-part requests. Following code demonstrates multi part requests using `requests`

```
import requests
url = "http://someurl"
files = {"file" : ("somename.txt", open("pathtofile", "rb"))}
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

This will give you an InMemoryFile in your server, which you can then save to your server using `default_storage` and `ContentFile` inbuilt in django

```
def filehandler(request):
    incomingfile = request.FILES['file']
    default_storage.save("pathtofolder", ContentFile(incomingfile.read()))
```